# how can I set/change the state upon clicking of a section in stacked bar chart plotted in D3.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I have plotted a stacked bar chart using `D3.js` now when the user clicks on one of the sections in the stacked bar chart I want to update the state `sectionSelected` to a specific text

This is the structure of my code :

```
class AnalysisDashboard extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            sectionSelected: ""
        };
        this.handleGraphSectionClick = this.handleGraphSectionClick.bind(this);
    }
    
    handleGraphSectionClick = (section) => {
        var test1 = '';
        console.log(this);
        this.setState({
            sectionSelected: section,
        });
    };
    
    static drawZddTrend(data, isModalActive, activeDivId) {
    
        AnalysisDashboard.plotHeadcountPracticeGraph(this.handleGraphSectionClick);
    }
    
    static plotHeadcountPracticeGraph(onClick) {
    
        //this is the graph plotting function
        bar.append("rect")
            .attr("y", function (d) { return y(d.data.practice); })
            .attr("x", function (d) { return x(d[0]); })
            .attr("width", function (d) { return x(d[1]) - x(d[0]); })
            .attr("height", y.bandwidth())
            .attr("cursor", "pointer")
            .on("mouseover", mouseover)
            .on("mousemove", mousemove)
            .on("mouseleave", mouseleave)
            .on("click", function (d) {
                text = "below-baseline"

                onClick(text);
            });
    }
}
```

It gives error:

> uncaught TypeError: onClick is not a function